# The type of this instance does not correspond to any type in the model

Tags: xdb, contact-facets, xconnect

I'm trying to create a custom facets to insert data into sitecore9 XDB through Xconnect for this, I have followed the [blog](https://citizensitecore.com/2017/10/17/xconnect-adding-custom-facets-in-sitecore-9/) and [XconnectDoc](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-model/facets/creating-facets/index.html?highlight=facet#use-custom-facets)

But when I'm trying to add data into contact custom facet- I'm getting error as **The type of this instance does not correspond to any type in the model** as shown in the below snapshot. However, I'm able to add facet data into the XDB for the buildin sitecore facets.

[image]

Here is the code Snippet for adding data into custom facet along with build in facet

```
 private static void AddContact()
{
    using (var client = GetClient())
    {
        //Multiple Identifiers can be added as below
        var identifiers = new ContactIdentifier[]
            {
                    new ContactIdentifier("user15", "SSkSudheer15", ContactIdentifierType.Known),
                    new ContactIdentifier("person15", "SSkSuggu15", ContactIdentifierType.Known)
            };

        Contact contact = new Contact(identifiers);
        client.AddContact(contact);

        // Optional thing to add based on the requirement
        PersonalInformation personalInfoFacet = new PersonalInformation()
        {
            FirstName = "Sudheer15",
            LastName = "Suggu15"
        };

        FacetReference reference = new FacetReference(contact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey);
        client.SetFacet(reference, personalInfoFacet);
        //client.SetFacet<PersonalInformation>(contact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, personalInfoFacet);

        EmailAddressList emailFacet = new EmailAddressList(new EmailAddress("Sudheer15@mail.com", true), "email");
        client.SetFacet(contact, emailFacet);

        var carDetails = new CarDetails()
        {
            CarName = "Benz",
            Model = "Mecedes",
            year = 2018
        };
        //FacetReference refernce = new FacetReference(contact, CarDetails.FacetName);
        //client.SetFacet(reference, carDetails);
        //client.SetFacet<CarDetails>(contact, CarDetails.FacetName, carDetails);
        client.SetFacet<CarDetails>(new FacetReference(contact, CarDetails.FacetName), carDetails);
        client.Submit();
    }
}
```

And the Model code snippet

[image]

I have added facet to a custom model and generated json file and dropped it in a different location in Xconnect root folder.

Custom Model code snippet:

```
 public class XconnectPOCModel
{
    public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();
    private static XdbModel BuildModel()
    {
        var builder = new XdbModelBuilder("XconnectPOCCarModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));
        builder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);
        builder.DefineFacet<Contact, CarDetails>(CarDetails.FacetName);

        return builder.BuildModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the facet to a custom model? Have you deployed your model to json and added them in the different places in xconnect?

Comment: Yes, I have a facet to a custom model and generate the json file and dropped in the xconnect App_data root locations.

Comment: Can you post the custom model code?

Comment: added code snippet

Comment: Did you also drop your model dll in this directory? c:\path\to\xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine 
The custom model seems fine

Comment: Yes, but no luck as well

Comment: Try changing the version of your model (in the XconnectPOCModel class) and add that model in the following 2 places:  
c:\path\to\xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker , 
c:\path\to\xconnect\root\App_Data\Models
Add the dlll to the following 2 places:
c:\path\to\site\bin\,
c:\path\to\xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine

Comment: also, don't forget to rebuild your model before exporting it to json, that caught me off guard multiple times

Comment: I have done the same steps that you have suggested above but still the same exception. Not sure what is missing there .. If you have any blog or  reference, Please provide those links to refer.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is the name of the model, but i asume you used the to json method from the blog you linked

Comment: I would start over using the docs now that you have an idea about how it should work

Comment: I have referred your previous question on Xconnect and I don’t see any difference in the code. May be I will try to recreate the model once again and will try. Meantime, if you have any solution please drop a note.. Thanks

Comment: i'm pretty sure your model code is fine, i think xConnect can't find your model, maybe try doing something else with the model like adding a custom event to see if that works

Comment: Well then, i redeployed my sitecore instance and now i am getting the same error, hit me up if you solve it :p i guess we're in the same boat now

Comment: I solved my issue, i hadn't deployed my events in Sitecore yet, that has nothing to do with Facets tho sorry

Comment: My issue is solved for no sitecore context and the same issue is presist in sitecore context. tell me if you have any Idea on this..

Comment: Mark, this issue was solved by adding a custom event to the custom model? I have same error while trying to add a contact using custom facets.

Comment: Raul, what is your exact issue?

Answer (score 6):

The error I got in code behind when creating contact, on client.submit() is: "The type of this instance does not correspond to any type in the model". I was currently checking with Sitecore Support team as they found in the logs provided that my custom facet types in the custom model can't be found in Model.Types even they exist there. 
The solution they provided and helped me was:
 XdbModel[] models = { CollectionModel.Model, xConnectIntroModel.CollectionModel.Model };

where xConnectIntroModel is my custom model.

Could you please add your custom model variable during initialization, restart Sitecore instance and try again:

```
 var collectionClient = new CollectionWebApiClient(new Uri(Constants.XConnectDomain.Url + "/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
            var searchClient = new SearchWebApiClient(new Uri(Constants.XConnectDomain.Url + "/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
            var configurationClient = new ConfigurationWebApiClient(new Uri(Constants.XConnectDomain.Url + "/configuration"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });

            XdbModel[] models = { CollectionModel.Model, xConnectIntroModel.CollectionModel.Model };

            var config = new XConnectClientConfiguration(new XdbRuntimeModel(models), collectionClient, searchClient, configurationClient);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add the below config patch in the xconnect client config file "App_Config\Sitecore\XConnect.Client.Configuration".
    **ContactCustomerInfoModel** is the model that i have created for Custom  facet.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <xconnect>
      <runtime type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.RuntimeModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
        <schemas hint="list:AddModelConfiguration">
          <schema name="ContactCustomerInfoModel" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration" patch:after="schema[@name='collectionmodel']">
            <param desc="modeltype">MyProject.Feature.Articles.CustomFacets.ContactCustomerInfoModel, MyProject.Feature.Articles</param>
          </schema>
        </schemas>
      </runtime>
    </xconnect>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by `@AmitKumar` you have to add a config path to initialize the model, however this config should be placed at the `CM` instance, like `App_Config\Include\xConnect.YourModel.config` unless the xConnect instance.

Another example:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <xconnect>
        <runtime type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.RuntimeModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
            <schemas hint="list:AddModelConfiguration">
                <schema name="UTMModel" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration" patch:after="schema[@name='collectionmodel']">
                    <param desc="modeltype">Sitecore.Foundation.XConnect.Models.UTMModel, Sitecore.Foundation.XConnect</param>
                </schema>
            </schemas>
        </runtime>
    </xconnect>
</sitecore>
```